# how to upload and save image in ajax and bootstrap modal

Tags: php

i want to upload and save image from bootstrap modal form by using ajax..I've done the coding for upload but the function upload is not working at all...I've done many thing but still does not work..can anyone help me to recognize where is my mistake actually?

this is my controller

```
public function director_add()
    {
        $data = array(
                 'photo' => $this->input->post('photo'), 
                'designation' => $this->input->post('designation'),
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'education' => $this->input->post('education'),
                'photo' =>$photo);

          $photo='';
            if(!empty($_FILES['userfile'])){
            $config['upload_path'] = './img/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

            //Load upload library and initialize configuration
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); //Returns array of 
             containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded.
            $picture = $upload_data['file_name'];   


            $insert = $this->director_model->director_add($data);
            echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
           }

    public function director_update()
  {
    $data = array(

            'photo' => $this->input->post('photo'),
            'designation' => $this->input->post('designation'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'education' => $this->input->post('education'),
            'photo' =>$this->input->post('photo'),
        );

          $data['photo']=$this->director_model
                           ->getImageFromId($_POST['directorID'])->photo;

     if(isset($_FILES['photo']))
     {
       $config['upload_path'] = './img/';
       $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

        //Load upload library and initialize configuration
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('photo');
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); //Returns array of containing 
        all of the data related to the file you uploaded.

        $data['photo'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
        }


    $this->director_model->director_update(array('directorID' => $this-
     >input->post('directorID')), $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
     }
```

this my view for my bootstrap modal that contain ajax and function for upload image

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
  $('#table_id').DataTable();} );
var save_method; //for save method string
var table;


function add_director()
{
  save_method = 'add';
  $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
  $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
//$('.modal-title').text('Add Person'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal 
  title
 }


function edit_director(id)
{
  save_method = 'update';
  $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

  //Ajax Load data from ajax
  $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/director_controller/ajax_edit/')?
  >/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('[name="directorID"]').val(data.directorID);

        $('[name="designation"]').val(data.designation);
        $('[name="name"]').val(data.name);
        $('[name="education"]').val(data.education);
        $('[name="photo"]').val(data.photo);

        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when 
       complete loaded
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit Director'); // Set title to Bootstrap 
         modal title
    },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
});
}


function save()
{
  var url;
  if(save_method == 'add')
  {
      url = "<?php echo 
      site_url('index.php/director_controller/director_add')?>";
  }
  else
  {
    url = "<?php echo 
    site_url('index.php/director_controller/director_update')?>";
  }

   $('#select_image').change(function(){3  
       $('#upload_form').submit();  
  });  
  $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
       e.preventDefault();  
       $.ajax({  
            url :"upload.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:new FormData(this),  
            contentType:false,  
            processData:false,  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#select_image').val('');  
                 $('#uploadModal').modal('hide');  
                 $('#gallery').html(data);  
            }  
       })  
  });  

   // ajax adding data to database
      $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
           //if success close modal and reload ajax table
           $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
          location.reload();// for reload a page
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
        }
    });
}

function delete_director(id)
{
  if(confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
  {
    // ajax delete data from database
      $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo 
        site_url('index.php/director_controller/director_delete')?>/"+id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
           location.reload();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error deleting data');
        }
    });

  }
}
```

```
<!-- Bootstrap modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
      label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
             <div class="form-group" id="photo-preview">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Photo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            (No photo)
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-
       primary">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-
     dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: It's bad that this isn`t working. But it would be good if you let us know "what is not working?". What are the errors you face, so on and so forth.

Comment: where is your file input?

Comment: @Nobody, I've error on adding n upload image to the database..when i want to add or upload image, it say that " error adding or uploading data"

Comment: @B.Desai, did you mean in model part?

Comment: No I mean i html code(in modal part) @FaizatulNajihah